How link code at runtime (Just in time compilation technique)?
I'm thinking about best way to create python baseline JIT compiler. The target - create linear code without jumps between opcode instructions in main interpreter loop. Is there any library which provides linker interface for C language? What literature do you recommend reading to study existing JIT compilation techniques (just remove jumps without optimization)?
